# Check to determine if user is logged properly in - php user system

Tags: php, authentication

Im in the process of writing a PHP user system. I cant quite figure out which variables I should check before its site load, in order to make sure which user is logged in, and that the user is not faked.

So far, I am saving the id of the user in a session variable and checking that one (ofc). Furthermore, I am saving the user_agent and checking that one as well. I don't quite feel that those two things alone is safe enough, though. What more should I check?
- I've been thinking about making an ip-check, but I'm afraid that this might change between site loads for some users..

Comment: the ip shouldn't change during a session but this is not save enough. You should generate a unique id for each session and check for this.

Comment: Even if I create a unique id and check for it, wouldn't that follow the session cookie if it gets hijacked?

Comment: If the session cookie gets hijacked and the hacker has the same ip you don't have any chance to distinguish them.

Comment: So ultimately, I keep doing what I already do; save userid and useragent. Furthermore, I implement an ip-check, saving the userip in a session and checking it against the actual ip each time.
Also, you think I should generate a unique id for each login? I guess I would save this in session variable as well as in a database table created to save those ids temporarily and deleting when user logs out again?

Comment: That's how I would do it but if you use `session_start();` and check in `$_SESSION` php should already do this kind of things for you.

Comment: So, basically the session_start(); function already operates with a unique id that gets checked? Well - why would you do it again, then? :)

Comment: I wouldn't use `session_start();` ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can go with email or username as it is unique for registration in your application.

Comment: Well, yeah.. I see your point, but if the purpose is to check for something that it wouldn't be possible to spoof in order to fake being logged in as someone else, would that get me any further?

Comment: @user2806026: The user cannot spoof the session variable as it lives on your server (assuming that you don't pass user input into it). There's little you can do against stealing the session cookie, except for using TLS, though.